# zurb_foundation layout generation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, zurb-foundation

I use gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0' and gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

After 'bundle install', I try to generate standart foundation layout templates ( 'rails g foundation:layout' ), I see 'Could not find generator foundation:layout.'

This is 'rails generate --help' output:

```
    Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

    General options:
      -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
      -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
      -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
      -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
      -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

    Please choose a generator below.

    Rails:
      assets
      controller
      generator
      helper
      integration_test
      mailer
      migration
      model
      observer
      performance_test
      resource
      scaffold
      scaffold_controller
      session_migration
      task

    Coffee:
      coffee:assets

    Foundation:
      foundation:install

    Jquery:
      jquery:install

    Js:
      js:assets
```

Whe I run 'rails g foundation:install', I have:

```
          insert  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
          append  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
        conflict  app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss
    Overwrite /Users/bmalets/Documents/ror_projects/easyprint/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Yes
           force  app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss
          append  app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss
          append  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
        conflict  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
    Overwrite /Users/bmalets/Documents/ror_projects/easyprint/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] Yes
           force  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

After I have empty application layout without vertical_menu template.
I have views with foundation style without top menu ( only application.html.erb in app/view/layouts/ ). What is the problem? Why zurb/foundation generators that are not loaded?

Comment: did you run `bundle install` after updating your Gemfile ?

Comment: also try `rails generate --help` it should list any zurb/foundation generators that are loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Foundation 4, the layout generation is included in the `foundation:install` generator, which, in your case, is actually available. Just run :

`rails g foundation:install`

You might also take a peek at the [actual source code](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/lib/foundation/generators/install_generator.rb) of the generator to see exactly what it does.